# Angular resolve within a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my global/main controller I load a few ngResources. How can I pause execution of anything else until loaded? similar to the resolve property of routes.

```
// The "global" controller in which I perform one time on load actions.
app.controller('FrontendCtrl', function($scope, authService, sessionService) {

  // Here I check if the user has a cookie and if so fetch info from server to reinit session
  authService.updateUser();

  $scope.$session = sessionService;

});

// Auth service
app.factory('authService', function($q, Auth, Other, sessionService) {

    // Populate local user data from server - one query followed by a few subsequent ones - all are ngResources
    var updateUser = function() {
      Auth.profile(null, function(data) {
        if(data) {
          $q.all({
            foo: Other.foo({ user_id: data.id }),
            bar: Other.bar({ user_id: data.id }),
           })
          .then(function(results) {
            sessionService.user = _.merge(results, data);
          });
        }
      });
    };
});

// In my view - this doesn't work if there is a delay in loading the updateUser function
{{ $session.user.name }}
```

Comment: Why not let the service return a promise that you use in your controller to populate your session?

Comment: @Edminsson +1, that's the best way, develop it in a full answer before I do.

Comment: @coma, go ahead my friend, develop it into a full answer.

Comment: @Edminsson - I have that but did not get it working until I forced the resolve. Docs mention that the view will resolve promises but in this case they do not. I have to call then() before assiging to scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of callbacks inorder to let the service go first to populate the session value, here is the code for you:

```
// Auth service
app.factory('authService', function($q, Auth, Other) {

    // Populate local user data from server - one query followed by a few subsequent ones - all are ngResources
    return {
      updateUser:  function(callback) {
        Auth.profile(null, function(data) {
          if(data) {
            $q.all({
              foo: Other.foo({ user_id: data.id }),
              bar: Other.bar({ user_id: data.id }),
             })
            .then(function(results) {
              //If sessionService is only an object in this case
              callback(sessionService);
            });
          }
        });
      };
    }

});
```

and in the controller:

```
// The "global" controller in which I perform one time on load actions.
app.controller('FrontendCtrl', function($scope, authService) {

  // Here I check if the user has a cookie and if so fetch info from server to reinit session
  //Update: Now a callback to fetch session data
  authService.updateUser(function(data){
    $scope.$session = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: I ended up using promises but this works as well so I will mark it as the answer.